# How to create a where clause with mysql to filter all values in varchr field different from 0 ?

Tags: mysql

i want to retrive all results in my table that have a value diferent from 0. 
I have a column that is a Varchar, the value inside is either a value of 0 or a string. 
I want to retrive all results that are not 0 
i tried

```
SELECT * FROM `book` `t` WHERE user_id= 62 AND payer != 0
SELECT * FROM `book` `t` WHERE user_id= 62 AND payer >= 0
```

i do not understand why the query above retrives all results including the onse that have 0 in the payer column

Comment: The first query should do what you want (although the standard inequality operator in SQL is `<>`, `!=` does the same thing).  Can you post sample data and the results you are getting?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM book t WHERE user_id= 62 AND TRIM(payer) <>  '0'` I suspect whitespaces

Comment: So i added the the hifens or quotes around the 0 and i put payer != '0' and it works , thanks for the input guys, important to understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the `0`.

```
SELECT * FROM `book` `t` 
WHERE user_id= 62 
AND payer <> '0'
```

Otherwise MySQL will try to convert your column values to a number to make the comparision with the number `0`. But the result of the conversion will be `0` and then all records of user `62` will match  since `0 = 0`

Comment: The OP states that the problem is that the query retrieves values of 0, not the other way around.

Comment: I know. Are you sure you understand the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work...with quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM `book` `t` WHERE user_id= 62 AND payer != '0'
```

and check for NULL values too if you need using `IS NULL`